# Microsoft push notification notificationId is blank

Tags: push-notification, azure-notificationhub

I am going thru Microsoft's documentation for sending a push notification. I have the notificationhub up and running, a basic android app. I can successful send a message via the portal to the app.
I am trying to send a message to the app via the code below but notification id is
always blank

Snippet of my code

namespace PushToApp
{
class Program
{

```
    static async Task Main()
    {
        var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .AddJsonFile("config.json", optional: false)
            .Build();

        var nhClient = NotificationHubClient.CreateClientFromConnectionString(config["PrimaryConnectionString"], config["HubName"], true);

        var message = "This a test";

        var fcmDeviceId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

        var fcmInstallation = new Installation
        {
            InstallationId = "fake-fcm-install-id",
            Platform = NotificationPlatform.Fcm,
            PushChannel = fcmDeviceId, 
            PushChannelExpired = false,
            Tags = new[] { "fcm" }
        };

        await nhClient.CreateOrUpdateInstallationAsync(fcmInstallation);
        await SendNotificationAsync(nhClient, message);
    }

    
    private static async Task SendNotificationAsync(NotificationHubClient nhClient, string message)
    {
        
        var alert = "{\"aps\":{\"alert\":\"" + message + "\",\"sound\":\"default\"}}";
        
        var outcomeFcm = await nhClient.SendFcmNativeNotificationAsync(alert);

        Console.WriteLine("result: " + outcomeFcm.Results.Count());
        Console.WriteLine("state: " + outcomeFcm.State);
        Console.WriteLine("Tracking Id: " + outcomeFcm.TrackingId);
        Console.WriteLine("notification Id: " + outcomeFcm.NotificationId);

    }
 } //class
```

} //namespace

`

Output:
Count: 3
result:1
state:DetailedStateAvailable
Tracking Id:a8b19b49-9857-401f-a1b1-af7dcb896e8b
notification Id:

Answer (score 0):

The NotificationId property is only set if you have the Standard Tier Subscription.

See the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/Microsoft.Azure.NotificationHubs.NotificationOutcome.NotificationId?view=azure-dotnet&viewFallbackFrom=netstandard-2.0).